# Copy Feature Classes in a String

Tags: copy, arcpy

I am trying to copy only feature classes I specify rather than copying them all using a if loop. I tried the below and it executes, but does not copy the files.

```
 import arcpy
 import os

 arcpy.env.workspace = r'c:\arcgis\ArcTutor\ModelBuilder\GTKModelbuilder\Data\RFDA Shapefiles'
 outWorkspace = r'C:\Output'

 fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

 for shapefile in fcList:
   if fcList == ('BedfordCalls.shp','ColleyvilleCalls.shp','HurstCalls.shp','KellersCalls.shp'):
    outFeatureClass = os.path.join(outWorkspace,shapefile.strip(".shp"))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shapefile, outFeatureClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import arcpy
 import os

 arcpy.env.workspace = r'c:\Shapefile'
 outWorkspace = r'C:\Output'

 fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

 for shapefile in fcList:
    if'BedfordCalls.shp'or'ColleyvilleCalls.shp'or'HurstCalls.shp'or'KellersCalls.shp' in fcList:
        outFeatureClass = os.path.join(outWorkspace,shapefile.strip(".shp"))
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shapefile, outFeatureClass)
```

Comment: There is some flawed logic in this. For each `shapefile` in `fcList`, you are going to check if any of several shapefile names are included in `fcList` and then copy `shapefile`. So if ListFeatureClasses returns say 15 feature classes and any of them are `'BedfordCalls.shp'` or one of the others you included, it will run `CopyFeatures_management` for all 15 feature classes.

Comment: Also, no need to strip the .shp extension off of shapefile. Copy Features is going to add it back on anyways because you're writing to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do what you want more effectively (noting comments on earlier answer):

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'c:\Shapefile'
outWorkspace = r'C:\Output'

fcList = ['BedfordCalls.shp', 'ColleyvilleCalls.shp', 'HurstCalls.shp', 'KellersCalls.shp']

for shapefile in fcList:
    outFeatureClass = os.path.join(outWorkspace, shapefile)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shapefile, outFeatureClass)
```